# Coffeescript class object in array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have some class with some functions and properties

```
exports.textareaWidget = class textareaWidget extends Widget
name = null    
getHtml: ->
        this.generateHtml(widgetHtml)
```

Then I create an object and add to array:

```
    obj = new w.textareaWidget()
    obj.name = "msgBody"
    console.log obj.getHtml() # works
    arr.push(obj)
# getting from arr
for field in arr
  result = result + field.getHtml()
```

When I want to get it from array I can access properites (name) but I can't access functions (getHtml). Why and how can I make it working ?
The error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getHtml'
```

Comment: `When I want to get it from array` can we see that code portion?

Comment: There's identation missing in `name = null` and `getHtml: ->`. Like this, these statements are not part of the class definition!

Comment: It was also hard to diagnose because you were not accessing name you were assigning to i,t therefore creating a new property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to indent the `name` and `getHtml` definitions:

```
exports.textareaWidget = class textareaWidget
  name: null    
  getHtml: ->
        this.generateHtml(widgetHtml)
```